# Drupal 8 Pass title from page to a webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

The problem i'm facing is that i have a list of let's say 5 jobs. Each job had it's own page and at the bottom of that page i have a button to apply for this job.

Now when you click the button a webform opens on a new page that you need to fill in in order to apply for that job.

The problem here is that when we receive mails, we don't know for what job they are applying.

A possible sollution would be to just pass the node title to a field in the webform or just in the mail they receive. But i can't seem to get this working.

I'm using the webforms module and the site is made in Drupal 8. suggestions are welcome in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest separating each job application form out and duplicating a template "job application" webform for each one so they're not all going to the same place. This will bring more clarity to your overall process and eliminate that issue.

Webforms for Drupal 8 provides pretty good templating options, so even if you don't have access to the content types/webforms backend yourself, an administrator should be able to create a "job application" template that you can create each time when you create a new job posting.

EDITED TO ADD:

You could also use a little php to get the page that sent you to the webform:

```
$ref = @$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]; //get referrer link
$nid = end(explode("/",$ref));  //get nid of referrer
$node_title = node_load($nid)->title; //get title of referring node
```

Where you put this code would depend on your overall setup, but you could likely add it to a field's default value.

Comment: i have admin rights since i'm developping the site. The thing is that the form is not on the same page as the job application, i know if we add a form to each job application it would work since we can just passs it through a view and display whatever we want but in this case  we need 1 form for all jobs and when you fill in the form the one who receives the mail needs to know what job he applied for.

Comment: thx! i will continue this site tomorrow or early next week, i'll give it a shot and keep you posted on the progress.

Comment: i tried out your solution but can't seem to get this working since it's custom php and i can't find a way to add the php to the page. any suggestions on ho to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this issue is that you can add a field of type "hidden" in your webform and set value from the available tokens like page title or url.

For eg: To set page title you can add value as

```
[current-page:title]
```

Don't know whether we can add a node title into it

**--OR--**

You can create it as a node or block it is well explained in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYBW2g0osd4

Comment: If you know any online reference please share

Comment: @Billa a plenty of tutorials are available in you-tube. Please see : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlTTkwdP_o

Comment: the problem is that the form is on a different node then the job application. So you basically need a string sent from a different node.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could probably use the first method mentioned above since the pages are different in that case.

Comment: yea it are indead different pages, that was the biggest problem, i know you can use those tokens but i scanned all of them and not a single token is refering to the page you are coming from. But i gues the answer  above might do the trick, i'll try it it out and keep you updated. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a entity reference field called "Attached Webform" on your node type
2. Set the default value of "Attached Webform" to your webform.
3. Do not display this field by going to form display settings and dragging "Attached Webform" to hidden.

Afterwards, you can access the node data through tokens, e.g. `[webform_submission:node:title]`

Also, if you edit the source of the webform, you can set the title of the form using:

```
'#title': 'Contact [webform_submission:node:title]'
name:
  '#title': 'Your Name'
  '#type': textfield
  '#required': true
  '#default_value': '[current-user:display-name]'
# ...
```